# 智渊别伤心爱兰可以帮你。 我们一起学习吧 in English please?

Tags: translation, meaning

My fried wrote 智渊别伤心爱兰可以帮你。
我们一起学习吧 to me. What does this mean?? I'm so curious. I tried google it  but gave me [image]

This weird answer.
(Btw, his  Chinese skills are not that advanced, so he might have used the google translator to translate this. If you think so, could you guess what it means??)

Oh and there's sth that I noticed, a dot in English typing is '.' While in Chinese, its 。is there a difference between these two??

Comment: `智渊` and `爱兰` seem to be someone's name, if no more context given. Google translation is good except these two names.

Comment: How are the names pronounced??

Comment: Oh and I thought 爱 meant sth like love

Comment: usual free online pinyin editor has . for Ascii, 。for Chinese

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at once

Comment: 智渊 fairly common Chinese given／first name／名, see web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this into parts and examine the meaning of each piece:

```
智渊 (pinyin: zhi-4 yuan-1)  [name] 
别   (bie-2)                 don't
伤心 (shang-1 xin-1)         be sad (be depressed, be upset, etc.)
爱兰 (ai-4 lan-2)            [name]
可以 (ke-3 yi-3)             can
帮   (bang-1)                help
你。 (ni-3)                  you.
我们 (wo-3 men)              we
一起 (yi-4 qi-3)             together
学习 (xue-2 xi-2)            study
吧   (ba)                    [ending exclamation]
```

Roughly translated, this means *Zhi-yuan, don't be upset! Ai-lan can help you. Let's study together!*

Based on this sentence, we can also guess some context: it is not uncommon in Chinese to reference oneself in the third person. I rewrite the translation to help you understand: *Zhi-yuan, don't be upset! I [Ai-lan] can help you. Let's study together!*

Let me try to guess some context. This sentence is probably related to school. You may have recently received some scores or grades, and you may not have done too well, so the speaker assumes/imagines that you are disappointed, and he is comforting you and offering help. If I am way off, you may laugh at me.

Amusing how much information one can infer from one sentence.

**P.S.** Regarding your concern that 爱 means love: you are right--typically used, it means love. However, when used in a name, it is literally part of the name. The word's meaning may give meaning/significance to the name, but it is essentially just the name. In the same way English has names such as Grace, Valentine, and Lily, Chinese has names made of common words that make certain names beautiful--and other names awkward...

**P.P.S.** Since Chinese is such a tremendously different language than English, and since its history is largely independent of English, it should not be too strange that the punctuation is different. In general, it it best that you use Chinese full-width punctuation (。，) when writing in Chinese and Latin half-width punctuation (.,) when writing in Latin-related languages.

Comment: Oh and I'm pretty sure that your guess is true because he goes to school